# React Leaflet Select multiple circles with holding shift and right click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I am using non-geographical map with multiple circles.

```
<Map
  ref={(map) => { this.map = map}}
  center={this.state.center ? this.state.center : this.getCalculatedCenterFromState()}
  zoom={this.state.zoom ? this.state.zoom : this.getCalculatedZoomFromState()}
  crs={this.mapService.getProjectionType()}
  zoomControl={false}
  dragging={ false }
>
  <FeatureGroup>
    <EditControl position='topleft'
                 onEdited={this._onEdited}
    />

    <Circle center={[51.51, -0.06]} radius={100} />
    <Circle center={[151.51, -0.06]} radius={100} />
  </FeatureGroup>
</Map>
```

I want to select both circle with holding `shift + ctrl` and `left click` if it is possible?

I also have react leaflet draw plugin, and I need to select multiple circles by holding `SHIFT` and `left click`.

By default `SHIFT + left click` show select box as zoom section as showed on image
[image]

I need to somehow override default leaflet behaviour and select those circles instead zoom in

Comment: It'd be better if you provide a simple working demo which will expose what is wrong and what are you going to achieve. Also there you can show what you've already tried.

Comment: I had update question with some code example. I tried to show the working example but unsuccessfully.